# BluetoothLEDevice NameChanged event not triggered

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-10, bluetooth-lowenergy

First of all excuse my poor knowledge of both the BLE Stack in UWP and the BLE specification itself. I have an UWP app that connects to a specific kind of BLE devices. One of the features these provide is a characteristic which, when written to, changes the name of the device.

When I trigger this change and consequently read the DeviceName characteristic (notice the UUIDs correspond to the standard):

```
var genericAccessServices = await SelectedDevice.GetGattServicesForUuidAsync(Guid.Parse("00001800-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb"));
var genericAccessService = genericAccessServices.Services.First();
var chars = await genericAccessService.GetCharacteristicsForUuidAsync(Guid.Parse("00002a00-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb"));
var deviceNameChar = chars.Characteristics.First();
var gattReadResult = await deviceNameChar.ReadValueAsync(BluetoothCacheMode.Uncached);
var reader = DataReader.FromBuffer(gattReadResult.Value);
byte formatType = 25;
var deviceNameString = BLEDeviceDescription.ReadBufferWithFormatType(reader, formatType, 20);
Debug.WriteLine($"New device name: {deviceNameString}");
```

I indeed get a name change, so the operation is successful. However, the NameChanged event from the BluetoothLEDevice is not triggered.

I then proceed to disconnect from the device using the procedure described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47702584/bluetooth-le-device-cannot-disconnect-in-win-10-iot-uwp-application/47708793).

Without closing the App, I then trigger a [DevicePicker](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.devices.enumeration.devicepicker?view=winrt-19041), to reconnect to the device and here the name did not change. If I close the app and subsequently reopen it the name briefly flickers but then appears correctly, as well as if I close the app and then try to connect from Windows settings.

How can you explain this behaviour? Does Windows cache the Device Name indefinetly during the lifetime of the App? Why is the NameChanged event not triggered? Any comments would be appreciated!

EDIT: - The target Windows Version is 1903 (10.0; Build 18362)

Comment: Could you share more detail about  specific kind of BLE devices and your app's target version OS system version?

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot say much about the Device, but I can't imagine how that makes a difference, maybe you have a more specific question? The name changes when the characteristic is read, but the NameChanged Event is not triggered.